# Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given

Tags: php, wordpress

I am on my WordPress website and these duplicate messages pop up on my dashboard. I am using WordPress 4.7.1. I do NOT have the FeedWordPress plugin on my site as I saw they had an issue with this error as well.

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, no array or string given in
>   /home/mydomain/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 298
>
> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, no array or string given in
>   /home/mydomain/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 298

This line is 298

```
$value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args );
```

This is the function that contains line 298

```
public function apply_filters( $value, $args ) {
    if ( ! $this->callbacks ) {
        return $value;
    }

    $nesting_level = $this->nesting_level++;

    $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] = array_keys( $this->callbacks );
    $num_args = count( $args );

    do {
        $this->current_priority[ $nesting_level ] = $priority = current( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] );

        foreach ( $this->callbacks[ $priority ] as $the_ ) {
            if( ! $this->doing_action ) {
                $args[ 0 ] = $value;
            }

            // Avoid the array_slice if possible.
            if ( $the_['accepted_args'] == 0 ) {
                $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array() );
            } elseif ( $the_['accepted_args'] >= $num_args ) {
                $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args );
            } else {
                $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array_slice( $args, 0, (int)$the_['accepted_args'] ) );
            }
        }
    } while ( false !== next( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] ) );

    unset( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] );
    unset( $this->current_priority[ $nesting_level ] );

    $this->nesting_level--;

    return $value;
}
```

Is this a serious warning? If so, how would I fix this?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/call_user_func_array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-valid-custom-function/ and [cross-site dupe](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108860/error-call-user-func-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-a-valid-callback)

Comment: I'm willing to bet the problem is with `add_filter` and wherever you're telling WP to call this

Comment: Unfortunately the error is misleading. The problem may be occurring on the line listed however it's triggered elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this thread - I had the same error upgrading to 4.7.2.  I deactivated my plugins one by one and found one to cause the problem

Comment: Please post the plugin name to help other users.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I disabled the Slider Revolution plugin and it fixes the issue.

Hope it helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This warning occurs when you add a function instead of a string in the callback argument of wordpress action hook.

**For an example:**

This will cause the warning:

```
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts",somefunction());
```

But this will not:

```
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts","somefunction");
```

Or,
This warning can also occur if the file containing that "somefunction" was not included.

These were the cases the warning was reproduced by me.